# What is the proper way to retrieve string key/values from Redis using BookSleeve 

Tags: redis, booksleeve

I'm new to BookSleeve and it seems that the API has changed even when compared to what is documented in the website.

AS it is noted in the website:

*"Note the API may change a little going to 1.0, but is stable enough to drive Stack Exchange.."*

So it seems that the documentation is not current anymore.

Anyway, the question is, what is the correct way to retrieve keys that you have previously stored.  I am using the 'String' API.

Is the following correct assumming an opened connection?:

```
var result = redisConnection.Strings.Get(0, "myKey");
byte[] buffer = redisConnection.Wait(result);
string str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `connection.Strings.GetString`. But if you do use System.Text.Encoding, then use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`. Redis strings are UTF8.